# IntelliJ adds Import to Gradle at Copy Task

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a very annoying and unexplainable behaviour in IntelliJ 2016.1:

If using Gradle copy task in a build file IntelliJ adds upon any edit in this file this import on top:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Copy
```

which is of course not necessary since this task is built-in Gradle.
Upon execution this leads to this error:

> Cannot create task of type 'Copy' as it does not implement the Task
>   interface.

Copy Task is just a simple one like this:

```
task copyNodeModules(type: Copy) {
    group="_webapp"
    from('./src/main/ts/node_modules') {
        include '**/*'
        exclude '**/lite-server'
        exclude '**/json-server'
        exclude '**/.bin'
    }
    into project.buildDir.path + '/resources/someFolder'
}
```

Comment: It seems that turning off "Add unambiguous Imports on the fly" (for Java!) helps - but this cannot be really the solution?

Comment: Can you add the gradle snippet for the Copy task.

Answer (score 18):

Going to
`Settings -> Auto Import -> Exclude from auto import and completion`

and adding 
`'com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler'` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

check your build.gradle see if it contains at the 1st line, just remove this line will fix the issue.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Copy
```